# How to take the derivative of the square root of a quadratic form

Tags: calculus, matrices

I want to take the derivative w.r.t $w$ of the following form: $\sigma_p = (w' \Sigma w)^{1/2}$, where $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of a random vector $R$, and $w$ is a weight vector of size ($n \times 1$) that sums to 1.

Using standard matrix derivative techniques I have:
$$
\frac{\partial \sigma_p}{\partial w} = \Sigma (\Sigma w) (w' \Sigma w)^{-1/2}
$$

I do not know how to proceed to get a clean form that is given in the solution: $\frac{\partial \sigma_p}{\partial w_i} = cov(r_i, r_p)$, where $r_i = R'e_i$, and $r_p = R'w$, $e_i$ is the vector with 1 in the position i and 0 everywhere else.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I have corrected some of my wordings. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\sigma_p^2=\sum^n_{i=1}w_i\sum^n_{j=1}\Sigma_{ij}w_j.$$

Differentiating with respect to $w_k$ gives

$$\frac{\partial \sigma_p^2}{\partial w_k}=\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{\partial w_i}{\partial w_k}\sum^n_{j=1}\Sigma_{ij} w_j+\sum^n_{i=1} w_i\sum^n_{j=1}\Sigma_{ij} \frac{\partial w_j}{\partial w_k}$$
$$=\sum^n_{j=1}\Sigma_{kj} w_j+\sum^n_{i=1} w_i \Sigma_{ik}\qquad\qquad\quad $$
$$=2\sum^n_{j=1}\Sigma_{kj} w_j\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

where the last line follows from symmetry of $\Sigma$. Thus

$$\frac{\partial \sigma_p}{\partial w_k}=\frac{1}{2\sigma_p}\frac{\partial \sigma_p^2}{\partial w_k}=\frac{\sum^n_{j=1}\Sigma_{kj} w_j}{\sqrt{w' \Sigma w}}.\tag{1}$$

Now, using the property of covariance: $\text{cov}(X,aY)=a\text{cov}(x,y)$, we know that $$\Sigma_{kj}w_j=w_j\text{cov}(r_k,r_j)=\text{cov}(r_k,w_jr_j).$$ Thus

$$\frac{\partial \sigma_p}{\partial w_k}=\frac{\sum^n_{j=1}\text{cov}(r_k,w_jr_j)}{\sqrt{w' \Sigma w}}=\frac{\text{cov}(r_k,R'w)}{\sqrt{w' \Sigma w}}=\frac{\text{cov}(r_k,r_p)}{\sigma_p}$$

where again we have a used a property of covariance: $\text{cov}(X,Y+Z)=\text{cov}(X,Y)+\text{cov}(X,Z).$

---

Using matrices, you should have got

$$\frac{\partial \sigma_p}{\partial w} = (\Sigma w) (w' \Sigma w)^{-1/2}$$

which is equation $(1)$. Then

$$(\Sigma w)_k=\text{cov}(r_k,w_jr_j)$$ and so $$\Sigma w=\text{cov}(r_k,R'w)=\text{cov}(r_k,r_p),$$

and the result follows. (It looks like there is a mistake in the expression you were trying to obtain.)